# Не получается запустить сервер на Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Доброе утро, помогите пожалуйста. Не получается запустить сервер на Rails. Ввожу команду `$ bin/rails server` и выходит ошибка

```
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.
The source does not contain any versions of 'pg'
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: Запуск `bundle install` нормально проходит?

Comment: Не нормально- выдает следующее:  bash: bundle: command not found

Comment: А bundler установлен? `gem install bundler` выполняли?

Comment: Спасибо, Василиса проблема была действительно в этом)